# Advanced folder synchronizing software

Tags: windows, software-rec, sync, filesystems

I am looking for a folder synchronization software for windows with advanced features like:

- Support of network shares
- Incremental sync
- Adding custom tasks and filters.

  - For example: Instead of copying an image file, create a thumbnail and save the thumbnail instead. Another example:
  - Another example: Instead of copying large files, it will only copy the filename with empty content.
- Logging

It also must be reliable, since the data copied is important to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been a fan of SyncBackSE, which should do what you are looking for.

Find it here: http://www.2brightsparks.com/index.html

There is a pay version, but also a free version: http://www.2brightsparks.com/download-syncback.html